# VirtualBox and group policy in Windows 2008

Tags: virtualbox, batch, gpedit

I have some batch files that start and save virtual machines on a Windows Server 2008 box. I am using gpedit.msc to fire the bats...

I have added lines to write to a logs. There is a line written, then `vboxmanage controlvm VM savestate` runs and then another line.

When the machine starts back up, same process; write a line, execute `vboxmanage`, write a line.

If I run the bat files from the desktop, they work just fine.
When I restart the machine, I can see that the logs have been written to, but the VMs are not going.

I guess I have 2 basic questions;
1) What would cause `vboxmanage` not to run, and 
2) as I am not skilled in batch files or VirtualBox, is there something I can do to detect and log what is happening?

Comment: How about you post the scripts in question?

Comment: The script is irrelevant (and, it works in every other situation) - I am just running `vboxmanage controlvm [VM] savestate` and `vboxmanage startvm [VM] --type headless` - the only way the script itself would be relevant is if there is some difference in the way it is executed at startup vs after login.